# Unable to instantiate function template when type argument is void

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

We know the following code [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/QLhCJ):

```
void f() {}
void g(void) {}

f();
g();
```

But why not the following:

```
template<typename T>
void f() {}

template<typename T>
void g(T) {}

f<void>();  //ok
g<void>();  //error
```

Why the line `g<void>()` [gives error](http://ideone.com/PP5mS)?

> error: no matching function for call to 'g()'

Why cant it be instantiated with `void` as type argument? Why the function template is not instantiated as:

```
void g(void) {}  //to be instantiated from the function template
```

After all, it is what I asked for.

I'm looking for an authoritative answer.

Comment: My guess is that it's because templates are not a textual replacement system.

Comment: That is fine, but what are the rules when type argument is `void`?

Comment: There was [gcc bug 51989](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332490/unable-to-instantiate-function-template-when-type-argument-is-void) - where GCC47 didn't liked void in templates.  It was fixed in 48.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: The URL in your comment points to this topic itself, not to the gcc bug. Could you please correct it so I can see the bug?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51989

Answer (score 5):

The legalistic argument is that `void` is an incomplete type that can not be completed, so can never be used as a top-level type. Compare with `void a;`. This is a bit confusing because `void` in an argument list is not a type, but a convention for indicating no arguments.

Comment: That I understand very well but why can't it be instantiated as `void g(void){}` which is valid?

Comment: @Nawaz : I would need someone familiar with the C++ standard to confirm this with  legalese, but `g(void){}` is valid only for C compatibility, that is, is compiled as is you wrote `g(){}`. The template `template <typename T> g(T){}` expects the function g to have **one and only one** argument of type T. `g(void)` is a function having zero arguments. You are mixing questionable syntactic sugar (the C convention) with actual C++ code (the fact T is the type of a parameter).

Comment: and to add to this correct answer, in C it is allowed (which causes sometimes compatibility problems with some libraries that do `void f(Void) {}` with a typedef for `void`).

Answer (score 3):

### C compatibility syntactic hack

The following:

```
void f() {}
void g(void) {}

f();
g();
```

compiles only because of a questionable C++ syntactic notation kept for C-compatibility reasons, that is, the `void` in g:

```
void g(void) {}
```

is here used to say "no parameters", and not, as could be expected "one parameter of type `void`" (which makes no sense).

In C++, we sometimes need to include C headers, so it would problematic if this notation was not supported. But it doesn't mean you have to use it in your C++ code.

### C++ templates

When you declare:

```
template<typename T>
void g(T) {}
```

You are declaring a function `g` templated on the type `T`, which has one unnamed parameter of type T.

So, when `T` is `void`, you are still working on a function `g`, which has one unnamed parameter of type `void`. Which makes no sense. Which means the compiler complains.

### Solution?

Seriously?

Don't use the `g(void)` notation at all. It's like typedef-ing structs in C++. It is useless and will only obfuscate the code.

### Solution 2?

Now, if you really have the following code:

```
template<typename T>
void g(T) {}
```

And if you want to provide a `g()` implementation, you should provide an overload:

```
// Original template
template<typename T>
void g(T) { /* implementation for the generic case */ }

// Code to handle g()
void g()  { /* implementation for the specific "void" case */ }
```

And if you want to provide a `g<void>()` implementation, you should provide a templated overload handling the void case through a specialization:

```
// Original template
template<typename T>
void g(T)      { /* implementation for the generic case for g(T) */ }

// Code to handle g<void>()
template<typename T>
void g()       { /* implementation for the generic case for g() */ }

template<>
void g<void>() { /* implementation for the generic case for g<void>() */ }
```

Comment: I know the alternative solutions myself. I didn't ask for that :-). My question wasn't about that. Basically, I'm looking for authoritative answer, which means, quoting relevant text from the Standard, which clearly (directly or indirectly) forbids what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Nawaz : `I know the alternative solutions myself.` : I figured so when I looked at your profile, but at the time, there was only one short answer, without standard quoting (and this is the case even now). And I figured that some people not familiar enough with C++ would like to have access to a more complete explanation, even if it lacked the standard extracts you wanted as an answer...